# How to accurately checks flat the surfaces

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am making an app that accurately checks how flat the surfaces, but the problem is when using core motion to get the accelerometer data, the value returned doesn't get fixed even if the surface is flat. So how can i check how the surface is flat?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nea3G.png

```
#define DRIFT_HZ 10
#define DRAFT_RATE 10

CMMotionManager *mManager = [CMMotionManager shareMotionManager];
if ([mManager isAccelerometerAvailable]) {
    [mManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:1/DRIFT_HZ];
    [mManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {

        CGPoint center = self.bubbleImageView.center;
        center.x -= accelerometerData.acceleration.y * DRAFT_RATE;

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.capsuleImageView.bounds, center)) {
            [self.bubbleImageView setCenter:center];
        }

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you havent yet, try playing with the motiongraphs sample application (in xcode). It'll give you a better understanding of how you might use a combination of "devicemotion" output such as roll, pitch, yaw; as well as gyroscope readings.

Relying on accelerometer readings alone is going to be tricky for your application idea (but maybe not impossible.) Accelerometer gives you a measure of G-force, so while there is a detectable difference between "flat" and "not so flat," there may be too much additional noise from other factors such as hand movement or variance between legacy device types to figure out a reliable algorithm.